# Why does passing an IP address instead of a domain name to a System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient cause it to throw an authentication error?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, dns, ip-address, lookup

I'm trying to send an email from a system which is trying to use as little bandwidth as possible. To this end, I've been caching DNS lookups locally and attempting to send direct to the IP address instead of the domain name.

This is the snippet which sends my data.

```
String^ _EmailServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
String^ _LoginName = "me@gmail.com";
String^ _LoginPassword = "mypassword";

System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient ^_SmtpClient = gcnew System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient(_EmailServer);

System::Net::NetworkCredential ^_NetworkCredential = gcnew System::Net::NetworkCredential(_LoginName, _LoginPassword);
        _
_SmtpClient->DeliveryMethod = System::Net::Mail::SmtpDeliveryMethod::Network;
_SmtpClient->UseDefaultCredentials = false;
_SmtpClient->Credentials = _NetworkCredential;
_SmtpClient->EnableSsl = true;

_SmtpClient->Send(_MailMessage);
```

Now the weird thing is that snippet works but if I do the DNS lookup myself and change `_EmailServer` to the IP address I resolved, the code above throws a `System::Security::Authentication::AuthenticationException` which says `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure`.

This fails even if I do the lookup and immediately try and send using the IP address I resolved.

Comment: Well, you're trying to use SSL, but the local side doesn't (now) know which domain name you're connecting to; the certificate server name will not match the IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason seems to be the fact that the server certificate is issued to domain smtp.gmail.com and when it gets compared to IP address (which you passes in) it fails as the cert domain doesn't match with the server address you passed i.e the IP address (instead of actual server name)

Comment: Thanks; I hadn't realised the domain was part of the certificate.